# Why won't the monitor go to sleep?

Tags: display, power-management, tablet

I have a Windows XP Tablet Edition running on an HP laptop.  The laptop is always plugged in.  I've set it up for the monitor to turn off after 10 minutes.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.  What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible issue is the sensitivity of some mice, especially gamer ones.
Mine, for example, often keeps my laptop from turning off the monitor.

Check if the system is actually detecting that you are idle, for example, launch some messenger clients, and see if they detect that there is no movement. If yes, then it's probably an issue of settings, like the other answer. If not, if they see you as "active", then it means movement is detected from mouse, or maybe from screen, since you use Tablet edition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to check whether it is on AC power or not! There are two options.

Apparently it's set to never go to sleep when it's on AC power, you have to configure the two, on battery and on AC power, hope that helps

[image: link text]

Comment: "watermark", on a Windows screenshot ? That's original.

Comment: Especially with the solid background and all, nobody will ever be able to get rid of it...

Comment: woteva just some twitter ads around!

Comment: Then -1 for this. It's a help site, not a place to advertise...